# Register/deregister element with something external to the component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am attempting to register/deregister an HTML element with something outside of the component, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the "correct" way to do it.

My instinct is to get a ref to the HTML element and then use an effect to synchronize that element with the external source.

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const registeredElements = [];

window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  if (registeredElements.some((element) => element.contains(event.target))) {
    console.log("clicked inside");
  } else {
    console.log("clicked outside");
  }
});

function registerElement(element) {
  registeredElements.push(element);
}

function unregisterElement(element) {
  const index = registeredElements.indexOf(element);
  if (index !== -1) {
    registeredElements.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const divRef = useRef();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const div = divRef.current;
      if (div) {
        registerElement(div);
        return () => {
          unregisterElement(div);
        };
      }
    },
    // What happens if the DIV element changes?
    []
  );

  return (
    <div ref={divRef} className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit youthful-shaw-2fbmc4]

The problem is that I'm not sure it will work if the div element gets updated, since my effect dependency array is empty. I would add the div element to the effect dependency array, but the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps lint rule says that you shouldn't depend on a ref.

The other two options I considered were:

1. Using a callback for the ref, but then I'm not sure how to unregister the element when it is unmounted.
2. Put the ref in state, but I don't want to re-render the component when the ref is registered, I just want to synchronize the ref with an external source.

What is the correct way to register/deregister an HTML element in this scenario?

Comment: It might be helpful to explain why you want to do this - what is your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`ref` callback functions](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#ref-callback) are what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I mentioned that as one of the options I tried and that I wasn't sure how to unregister the element in that case. One of my colleagues pointed out that the callback function will receive `null` on unmount which will allow me to unregister the element, but I think I'll still need to keep a ref to the old element in order to unregister it. With that additional context, that answers my question.